# Internet Explorer -- way to have user dump current preferences into log file and send to me

Tags: internet-explorer

Subject says it all.

Is there a user-proof way for a user to press a button on their Windows machine which will cause them to be presented with their IE settings in a log file format (just plain text) which can then be emailed to me.

I'm doing a registration script that requires cookies and javascript to be turned on, and I have a cookie/script test page that is failing something like .2% of the time.

I'd like a fool-proof way to detect that support for javascript is turned on and that the cookie settings are at a high enough threshold.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Cookies might be filtered by a proxy, mightn't they, somewhere between the browser and the server?

Comment: truth.  but still doesn't answer question...

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the techniques [this site is engaging](http://www.solidview.com/soos/login2.asp).
There are two links to check for `javascript` and `cookies` being enabled.

I expect without `javascript`, checking `cookies` will not work.
So, you need to check in that order.

I suggest downloading the **`html`** pages linked on that page to check them.

Comment: You suggestion does not attempt to answer my question.  FWIW, I have built a cookie/script detection process.  That is easy.  Reaching into a _still_complaining_ users machine is not.

Comment: I found the notes at http://www.solidview.com/soos/login.asp good enough to push me through the necessary unlocks on my firefox extensions.